# Image byte[] into matlab

Tags: c#, .net, image, matlab

I have a 24 bit image RGB which is represented as packed byte array .

meaning the array looks like so: R,G,B,R,G,B....

I have complied file of Matlab into dll and I want to send the array into it.

```
   RGBImage image = _currentImage as RGBImage;
   MWArray MatlabArray = new MWNumericArray(image.Height, image.Width, image[0].Data);
```

this fails;

however almost the same code

```
    BayerImage Image = _currentImage as BayerImage;            
    MWArray MatlabArray = new MWNumericArray(_currentImage.Height, _currentImage.Width, Image.GetBayerArrayAlignedRight());
```

works like a charm.
never mind the alignment to the right. my image size is 768X1024X3 = 2359296.
i'm missing something in building the MWArray because i'm getting this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in CCMPlugin.dll

Additional information: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray' threw an exception.
```

can you please tell me what is wrong with the way i'm transferring the byte array into MWArray?

Comment: I am guessing that `image` does not have an element `[0]`. How can `image.Height` and `image[0].Data` both be valid syntax?? To have an element `[0]` you have to be a pointer. To have an element `.Height`, not.

Comment: it has element [0]. it's a derived class you can overload the operators. all the info is ok. however i'm using the wrong constructor. this is what i have figured out so far

Comment: Are you sure you don't need `image.Data[0]` ? Since you say the data is stored in packed RGBRGBRGB format, that would make more sense?

Comment: yes it's a class we built, image[0] represent the channel of the image. however here we use only one channel.

Comment: Well, if you're sure. It's an unusual way of representing things. But then I'm out of ideas, sorry. You should show your class definition and constructor, since it's the one throwing the exception.

Comment: Isn't the problem in `BayerImage` then? I think it would be relevant to see the code for that.